# How to create only angular application from JHipster with config file not answering questions

Tags: angular, jhipster, jhipster-registry

I want to create only an angular(frontend) application using JHipster from a config file like instead of answering questions one config file it should generate automatically

Answer (score 1):

You can design and generate your application using [JDL](https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/applications). You can also use [Jhipster Online](https://start.jhipster.tech) to store your JHipster model files or even generate and download the whole application as a zip.

To give you a very tiny example of what you want:

```
application {
  config {
    baseName MyApp,
    applicationType monolith,
    authenticationType jwt,
    skipServer true
  }
  entities *
}

// Define your entities here
```

`skipServer true` will generate only the frontend, and the default frontend is Angular. I have not tested this with the last version, it's just so you get the general idea.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid those default modules(like admin,home,shared) generated by jhipster

Comment: how to run that file jhipster app jhipster-jdl.jh is not working

Comment: Well, there's the option `skipUserManagement` but the default value seems to be `true`. I dont know of a way to skip the other general use modules. As for the command, you can use `jhipster import-jdl your-jdl-file.jh`.